# How can I set a JS variable to what a SOAP Function returns?

Tags: javascript, php, soap, soap-client

I have a PHP function GetResult which returns an array. In a Javascript file, I am trying to do the following:

```
var c = SOAPClient.invoke("/path", "GetResult", p1, true, callback);
```

However, the variable c is undefined. How can I set it to the returned array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you call the callback function?

```
var c;
function callback(arr) {
    c = arr;
}
```